# django: formfield_for_foreignkey won't let me create new inline objects

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the following model:

```python
class Benchmark(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    platforms = models.ManyToManyField('Platform')

class Platform(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class KnobItem(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    knob = models.ForeignKey('Knob')

class BenchmarkKnobItem(KnobItem):
    benchmark = models.ForeignKey('Benchmark')

class PlatformKnobItem(KnobItem):
    platform = models.ForeignKey('Platform')

class Knob(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

In the admin, I have `BenchmarkKnobItem` and `PlatformKnobItem` as inlines.  The drop-down menu for adding a new benchmark knob has the unwanted effect of also listing available platform knobs. I then used the `formfield_for_foreignkey` method for the available knobs to their respective benchmark or platform models.

```python
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "knob":
        kwargs["queryset"] = BenchmarkKnobItem.objects.all()
    return super(BenchmarkKnobItemInline, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Unfortunately, this won't allow me to create a new inline object.  The admin says "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices." I'm assuming this is because the object hasn't been saved yet.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to allow me to create new knobs while still restricting the available choices to their respective types?

Comment: Filed under the "any ideas" heading, subsection "untested", have you tried playing with the [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) argument of model.ForeignKey? Aside from that, a screenshot of the problem would be nice: confusing class names + backward and forward foreign key references + "I don't know which which model you're talking about when you say _the admin_" is doing my head in ;)